# loading data which are seperated by comma(,) to seperate textviews in android

Tags: android, xml, textview

hii every buddy,

i am parsing a xml file am loading parsed data to a textview,in the xml i hav data like
Yes,No,DontKnow  i need to load each data to seperate text view, i.e 'Yes' should be loaded to a textview,&'No' should be loaded to other textview & Dontknow should be loaded to another,can any one tell me how can i do thanx in advance